# Jquery dropdown combobox doesn't show added items which I get from Server

Tags: jquery

I have used upload combobox component from jquery rains - http://www.jqueryrain.com/?Vn3Q3xQR

Now if I add combobox options to the combobox, from a server-side response it will not show newly added response, Here is my code

```
// Send request to server to get items to fill in combobox
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comboitems.php",
    data: [],
    success: function(result, success, response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(result));
        var myOptions = JSON.parse(result);

        $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
            $('#combo').append( new Option(text,val) );
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the link you provided ;)

You need to refresh the component, Simply this will do.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comboitems.php",
    data: [],
    success: function(result, success, response) {
        var myOptions = JSON.parse(result);

        $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
            $('#combo').append( new Option(text,val) ).multipleSelect("refresh");
        });
    }
});
```

When you create component of multipleselect using combobox, it actually hides the combobox creates new jquery ui components, using divs and listitems it shows various combox box items, So this component will get all the items from the original combo and generate the multipleselect component

So now when you add item you need to tell the component that original combobox is update, so you have to refresh the view

If you will inspect DOM, you will find combobox element as hidden.